# Sorting data by timestamp on ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I've looked at a few examples, but haven't been able to reverse-sort, so that newly generated objects are on top.

My sortable items are in components, and I don't think I'm passing sortProperties & sortAscending correctly.

lavender.js:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['application'],

    sortProperties: ['timestamp'],
    sortAscending: false
});
```

lavender.hbs

```
{{#each model.comment as |comment|}}
    {{comment-thread message=comment.message user=comment.user timestamp=comment.timestamp sortProperties=sortProperties sortAscending=sortAscending}}
{{/each}}
```

comment.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  message: DS.attr('string'),
  timestamp: DS.attr('date'),

  user: DS.belongsTo('user', {async: true}),
  todo: DS.belongsTo('todo', {async: true}),

});
```

todo.js (model for lavender.js)

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    isCompleted: DS.attr('boolean', {defaultValue: false}),
    detail: DS.attr('string', {defaultValue: "add details.."}),

    comment: DS.hasMany('comment', {async: true}),
});
```

There must be something I'm not seeing.. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use deprecated `Ember.ArrayController` instead of `Ember.Controller` if you want your approach to work or you can choose other approach.

The best approach is to use `Ember.computed` macro:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['application'],

    commentsSorting: ['timestamp:desc'],
    comments: Ember.computed.sort('model.comment', 'commentsSorting')
});
```

Then, instead of `model`, iterate over `comments` in your template.

You can also use computed property and private(discouraged) `Ember.ArrayProxy`, like this:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['application'],

    comments: Ember.computed('model', 'model.comment', function() {
      return Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.SortableMixin, {
        sortProperties: ['timestamp'],
        sortAscending: false,
        content: this.get('model.comment')
      });
    })
});
```

Then you can iterate over `comments` in your template:

```
{{#each model.comment as |comment|}}
    {{comment-thread message=comment.message user=comment.user timestamp=comment.timestamp}}
{{/each}}
```

I don't think you need to pass sort properties to `comment-thread`, I don't you've misunderstood how this works. It gets sorted in controller, where are all records, not in component, where you have only 1 record per 1 component and no reference to other records.

Comment: Thank you! Per your recommendation, I chose to implement Ember.computed macro. I'm new to ember so I've got some basic questions..

What does 'timestamp:desc' represent?

and do I replace Ember.computed.sort('model') for Ember.computed.sort('comments')?

Comment: Also how do I iterate ember.computed over comments in the template?

Comment: 1) `timetamp:desc` means that you want to sort by `timestamp` property descending. 2) I put there `model`, but I see you iterate over `model.comment`, so `model.comment` should be there(if this is an array of models, I don't know you didn't give the code for model). 3) Comments is sorted `model.comment`, so you iterate iver `comments` in your template.

Comment: I get an error: Uncaught Error: Computed Property declared without a property function

Comment: Maybe it would be solved by adding  ).property('commentsSorting')?

Comment: I'm still doing ember.computed macro approach.

Comment: Wow it worked! I just needed to make sure to iterate over "comments" that's below commentsSorting. Thank you so much!!!